# What is the equivalent method of javascript looping data from an object and rendering it via html for php?

Tags: php

So in javascript its pretty simple to create an object like so...

```
var myObject = [

                {
                    name: 'hello',
                    url: 'https://www.google.com',
                    img: 'ico1.png'
                },

                {
                    name: 'hello2',
                    url: 'https://www.something.com',
                    img: 'ico2.png'
                },
```

and then i'd just run a simple loop and it would render out my data like this

```
let renderedHtml=myOpject.map(function(item){
       return `<h1>${item.name}</h1><a href="${item.url}"></a><img src="${item.imgFile}"/>`
    });


<h1>hello1</h1>
<a href="url"></a>
<img src="ico1.jpg">

<h1>hello2</h1>
<a href="url"></a>
<img src="ico2.jpg">
```

Whats the easiest way to do this in php?

Answer (score 1):

Any loop can get it done but the easiest one is foreach():
[More on Foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
<?php 
foreach($myObject as $key => $value){
    ?>
    <h1><?= $value->name ?></h1><a href="<?= $value->url ?>"></a><img src="<?= $value->imgFile ?>"/>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: is creating the object the same too? or is it completely different?

Comment: @tjlee to create object, you need to firstly to create a class (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php). But you can use arrays too, if you don't need some additional behavior or logic